# Texbook typo? Divergence Criterion for Functional Limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-limit-theorems

[image: Here's a picture]

The last sentence should say "lim f(x) does not exist", rather than "lim f(c) does not exist", correct?

Answer (score 2):

Agree.  "$\lim_{x\rightarrow c} f(x)$ does not exist."